# NTFS Drives suddenly mount as read-only, how to fix?

Tags: mount, ntfs, read-only

my NTFS drives have always mounted with write access now suddenly they don't. How do I get them to mount with write access?

I mount them simply by going to "other locations" and clicking the drive.

I'm on Ubuntu Budgie 18.04.

Comment: Boot up Windows and scan the drive for errors. You probably left it mounted when rebooting.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you solved your own problem, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! :-) I took the liberty to revert the change that added the answer but you can always review a post’s history through the link below it.

Answer (score 2):

if you have dual boot and have windows installed. make sure that "fast startup" is disabled in windows settings and then reboot. latest windows update re-enables the fast startup.